# What does `-` mean in command `ls -la | vim -`?

Tags: terminal

I got to know commands like `ls -la | vim -` can be used to open Linux command output in vim.

1. What does `-` mean after vim?
2. Is it some kind of special switch?
3. Why doesn't simply using `ls -la | vim` works ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from `help --` :

**Start editing a new buffer, which is filled with text
that is read from stdin.**

`ls | vim` doesn't work, because vim reads it's commands from the terminal (as opposed to the content of a buffer)